# B is a subring of A and f is a homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $A$ and $B$ be rings, and $f: A \rightarrow B$ a homomorphism. Prove that $f(A)=\{f(x): x\in A\}$ is a subring of B.

To begin, I need to prove there are subtraction and multiplication for $B$ to be a subring. I've started with attempting to prove $a+(-b) \in f(A)$ for $a,b\in A$.
So $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ are in $f$ because $f$ is a homomorphism. So $f(a+b)$ is also in $f(A)$ thus $f(a+(-b))\in f(A)$ so $a+(-b)\in A$

Now proving $ab\in f(A)$ for $a,b \in A$. I started with $f(a)$ and $f(b) \in f$ because $f$ is a homomorphism, thus $f(ab)$ is also in $f(A)$. QED and B is a subring?

Comment: Could you clarify a bit? $A$ and $B$ are only related by homomorphism, so they're not guaranteed to have the same elements. In the second sentence of your proof, you let $a + (-b) \in f(A) \subset B$, but also $a, b, \in A$. This wouldn't make sense, for instance, if $A$ was a cyclic ring and $B$ was the set of all movements on a Rubik's Cube.

Comment: I guess they wouldn't share elements per say. I know elements of $A$ are mapped to $B$ and elements of $A$ are mapped to $f(A)$ so are $B$ and $f(A)$ should relate

Answer (score 1):

We want to show that :

- $1_{B}\in f(A)$
- $a,b\in f(A)\Rightarrow a-b\in f(A)$
- $a,b\in f(A)\Rightarrow ab\in f(A)$

Let $a=f(c)$, $b=f(d)$, for $c,d\in A$

- The first should be obvious.
- For the second observe that $f(c)-f(d)=f(c-d)\in f(A)$.
- For the third observe that $f(c)f(d)=f(cd)\in f(A)$.